# How to only get files without extensions?

Tags: python, file, path, filenames, listdir

My problem is to get ONLY files without extensions.
I mean - I have a dictionary and there are some files without extensions and some files with extensions (.xml, .csv, etc)

I want that my code would **only** read files without extensions.

Now, it's reading every file in the dictionary "Dir".

```
path = 'C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Dir/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?#os.path.splitext might come in handy

Comment: "I have a dictionary" vs `for filename in os.listdir(path):` – which is it? Do you only want to work on file names which do not have an extension, or do you want to ignore the extension in the file name?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I want to work on files which don't have an extension

Comment: How do you define a file "without extension"? A file not ending with `.` and 2/3/4 chars? In that case search for files not containing `.` in filename; but that may filter some positive results, too.

Comment: @AzharKhan Filename extensions are typically 2-4 characters but that's merely a convention. There are no limits other than any constraints on filename lengths on the platform in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no dots in your files, you can do :

```
path = 'C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Dir/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if '.' not in filename:
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can split the filename using the *splittext* function and check for the ones which are not a directory and do not have an extension value (ext).

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not os.path.isdir(filename): 
        (name, ext) = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if not ext:
            # Your code here
```

Comment: This is a superior solution to just searching for '.'